# Split Product SKU - Google Analytics

Tags: magento, analytics, skus

I have a magento store, and I use custom options, so my product SKU's come out like this:
NMO-DBSZ-SLKK-SKKZS-XBONE-CAZZ

What I want to do is create a report of each individual SKU so I can get daily/weekly totals of individual products purchased. Currently, I have my purchases tracked in Google Analytics Conversions/Ecommerce, and it gives me some pretty good info, but not everything I'd like.

Is there anyway I can grab the SKU information in GA, split it apart, remove the dash and just total up the individual product sku's?

NMO - 22 Units

DBSZ - 12 Units

SLKK - 10 Units

etc.

Comment: Google sees your skus as a whole sku (not sub skus), so you can't do that directly from GA.  You could try exporting a CSV report from Google Analytics and filtering it in a way to view that information.

Comment: yea I was wondering if there was a way to split the sku with a regular expression on google analytics, I have a lot of data and would like this automated instead of having to manually organize everything